AWS Glue + RDS Postgres
can anyone give any advice on this.
I created the very simple test Glue job: Source - RDS Postgres, Destination - S3 bucket.
Run takes about 23 minutes and ends with timeout error.
In the log I see "AWSGlueJobExecutor; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException", but if I replace Source with S3 (instead of RDS Postgres) - so, the source is S3 and the destanation is S3 it ends successfully. And if I replace Destination with RDS Postgres, so the Source is RDS Postgres and the Destination is RDS Postgres - it ends successfully too.
Here is the log file: text
So what should I do ?
P.S. And what do you think about Glue in general - for me it seems very unfriendly and buggy.
